# how to persist Quartz Scheduler trigger in database , when deploy war file in tomcat with grails version 2.3.7

Tags: java, tomcat, grails

how to persist Quartz Scheduler trigger in database , when deploy war file in tomcat with grails version 2.3.7 and quartz scheduler version is 2.2.1

please help us.

Comment: http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering

Comment: thanks for reply but when we are deploying war in tomcat trigger is not going to persist. so this is the problem.

Comment: Ok, did you create the right db schema (from the Quartz distribution's "docs/dbTables" directory)? Does application startup throw any errors? What does your [config](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/configuration/ConfigJobStoreTX) look like?

Comment: yes but problem is Quartz.properties file name. and solve out by name of quartz.properties . thanks for ur valuable response.